# Force split SQL request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm stuck with an SQL problem here :

```
tab = ["medium", "good", "excellent", "mother_tongue"]

users = User.joins(:spoken_languages).where("language = 'FR' and level in (?)", tab).count
```

> SELECT COUNT(*) 
>       FROM "users" INNER JOIN "spoken_languages" 
>       ON "spoken_languages"."languageable_id" = "users"."id"
>       AND "spoken_languages"."languageable_type" = 'User' 
>       WHERE (language = 'FR' and level in ('medium','good','excellent','mother_tongue'))

```
users.joins(:spoken_languages).where("language = 'NL' and level in (?)", tab)
```

> SELECT COUNT(*) 
>       FROM "users"
>       INNER JOIN "spoken_languages"
>       ON "spoken_languages"."languageable_id" = "users"."id"
>       AND "spoken_languages"."languageable_type" = "User"
>       WHERE (language = 'FR' and level in ('medium','good','excellent','mother_tongue')) 
>       AND (language = 'NL' and level in ('medium','good','excellent','mother_tongue'))

I don't want rails to check this column simultaneously but separately.

Firstly check French users with required level then in this list Dutch users with required list

Here, rails is looking for users with a languages record 'FR' AND 'NL'. A language record is only NL Or FR not both.

Comment: in which case you check for Dutch list, in any or conditionally?

Comment: I've a slider 0 - 5 which represent level, if the slider (for french or dutch) is greater than 0 I apply the filter